# Rails app hosted on heroku says Google Analytics is not installed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-analytics

Okay so I've created a rails app to which I've added the google analytics tracking code. The problem is that the google analytics page is saying the tracking code is not installed. Here is the tracking code. Note I'm using a heroku domain (https://ligabox.herokuapp.com)

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'herokuapp.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I almost sure I'm missing something simple here, something related to the domain name or the heroku setup, but I've been at this for a while and my previous investigations on this problem have led to no result, so I'm hoping someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: How much have you waited? Detection takes more time, even when Google tells you: `Last updated: some date` in Analytics status, I had to wait some more time having installed code before `some date`.

Comment: Just check have you added this config "heroku config:add GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"

Comment: @ArihantGodha it seems to be working fine now, although I haven't added that config, is it necessary?, what would this actually do? (I'm a noob in rails and heroku) thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look in the network tab of most browsers you'll be able to see the requests that your site is sending to Google so it's just a case of waiting until your data starts appearing - here's what I see loading your site. Also you can use the new 'live' views in Google Analytics just to be sure.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I had seen the network calls, and you guys are right, it just took more time, it's working fine now, thanks!